# Keras model.evaluate() failing

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I have created a little ConvNet which look likes this:

```
model = Sequential()
optimizer = Adam()

model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x / 127.5 - 1., input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I am training it with data of shape

```
X_train.shape = (48000, 28, 28, 1)
X_val.shape = (12000, 28, 28, 1)
```

And it works well.

However, I would now like to test the model using `keras.evaluate()` function:

```
score = trained_model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=128)
# X_test.shape = (10000, 28, 28, 1)
# y_test.shape (10000,)
```

Which result in the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (10,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

I don't quite understand this error, given that I use the same shape for my training, validation and test set.

Would you mind explaining what my error is, and how to fix it?

Many thanks!

Edit: Output of `trained_model.summary()`

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
lambda_1 (Lambda)            (None, 28, 28, 1)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 26, 26, 64)        640
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 13, 13, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 13, 13, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 10816)             0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               1384576
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 10)                1290
=================================================================
Total params: 1,386,506
Trainable params: 1,386,506
Non-trainable params: 0
```

**Solution given in the comment** 
 
I forgot to one hot encore my `y_train`, `y_val` and `y_test` data. 
Solved with:

```
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
```

Comment: How many `class` do you have?

Comment: You haven't one-hot encoded the target

Comment: I have 10 classes. 
@SreeramTP Is it the real problem here?

Comment: @Mornor was you able to train the model.? what is y_train.shape .?

Comment: I am indeed able to train the model. `y_train.shape = (48000,)`

Comment: That's weird you model expects a 10 dimensional output and you were able to train it on a one dimensional target.? Please do cross check the saved model using `trained_model.summary()`. And make sure the model you have  trained and trained model are the same

Comment: They are indeed the same model :(

Comment: can you update the question with `trained_model.summary()` .?

Comment: I updated the question, thanks!

Comment: I tried to train that model with a 1d vector as target. But it gives error as expected. I don't know what is happening in your case. Recheck the code to see any mistakes in data prep or model saving is present

Comment: The problem is with y_test, not with y_train, you didn't one-hot encode it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that the targets (the y's) are expected to have a shape that is one-hot encoded, each sample with 10 elements. You show that y_test has shape (10000,), which is not one-hot encoded.

You can do this with:

```
y_test = kera.utils.np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)
```